# Зачем применяется mapTrackerToProps в react redux meteor?

Tags: reactjs, redux, meteor

В mapStateToProps можно достать данные из store и сразу передать в props.

В mapDispatchToProps можно передать в props actions.

А что такое mapTrackerToProps и для чего применяется?

```
export default connectMeteor(mapTrackerToProps, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-redux-meteor` совмещает в себе библиотеки `react-redux` и [react-meteor-data](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data), поэтому аргументы `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` это аргументы из функции `connect` из `react-redux`, а `mapTrackerToProps` это аргумент функции `withTracker` из библиотеки `react-meteor-data`.

Т.е. в `mapTrackerToProps` нужно передать функцию, которая будет получать реактивные данные (в основном это запросы БД minimingo). Например:

```
const mapTrackerToProps = (state, props) => {
  if (Meteor.subscribe('posts').ready()) {
    return { posts: Posts.find().fetch() };
  }
  return { posts: [] };
};
```